# Is there a closed form for this transcendental equation?

Tags: closed-form, transcendental-equations

Wondering if there’s a closed form for $\exp(\frac{1}{\log(x)})=\frac{x}{e}$?

Numerically solving yields $x \approx .539$

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+e%5E%281%2Flog%28x%29%29+%3D+x+%2Fe) says, that also $x \approx 5.04317$ is a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\exp \left (\dfrac{1}{\ln x} \right ) = \dfrac{x}{e}; \tag 1$

$\dfrac{1}{\ln x} = \ln \left ( \dfrac{x}{e} \right ) = \ln x - \ln e = \ln x - 1; \tag 2$

$1 = (\ln x)^2 - \ln x; \tag 3$

$(\ln x)^2 - \ln x - 1 = 0; \tag 4$

quadratic formula:

$\ln x = \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt 5}{2}; \tag 5$

$x = \exp \left ( \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt 5}{2} \right ).  \tag 6$

***Some Additional Observations:***

From (5),

$\dfrac{1}{\ln x} = \dfrac{2}{1 \pm \sqrt 5} = \dfrac{2(1 \mp \sqrt 5)}{(1 \mp \sqrt 5)(1 \pm \sqrt 5}$
$= \dfrac{2(1 \mp \sqrt 5)}{1^2 - (\sqrt 5)^2} = \dfrac{2(1 \mp \sqrt 5)}{1 - 5} = \dfrac{2(1 \mp \sqrt 5)}{-4} = - \dfrac{1 \mp \sqrt 5}{2}; \tag 7$

and also from (5)

$\ln x - 1 = \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt 5}{2} - 1 = \dfrac{-1 \pm \sqrt 5}{2} = - \dfrac{1 \mp \sqrt 5}{2} = \dfrac{1}{\ln x}; \tag 8$

from (6),

$\dfrac{x}{e} = xe^{-1} = \exp \left ( \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt 5}{2} \right )e^{-1} = \exp \left ( \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt 5}{2}  - 1 \right )$
$= \exp \left ( -\dfrac{1 \mp \sqrt 5}{2} \right ) = \exp \left ( \dfrac{1}{\ln x} \right ); \tag 9$

we also note that (4) yields

$\ln x( \ln x - 1) = 1 \Longrightarrow \dfrac{1}{\ln x} = \ln x - 1, \tag{10}$

in agreement with (8).

The reader is advised to take some care in keeping careful track of the $\pm$ and $\mp$ signs occurring in the above, since I have taken some liberty in their use.  But the intended meaning shouldn't be too hard to discern.

The reader may recall that the quadratic equation

$\phi^2 - \phi - 1 = 0, \tag{11}$

whose roots are of course

$\phi = \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt 5}{2}, \tag{12}$

and obey

$\dfrac{1}{\phi} = \phi - 1, \tag{13}$

in fact quantifies the cassical *golden section*, which is the ratio of the sides of a rectangle such that if a square whose side is the shorter is removed the remaining rectangle is in the same proportion as the original.  So apparently what we're looking at here is the exponential/logarithmic version of that.  The further pursuit of this correspondence fascinates, but will be deferred to a later time.

Comment: HI, approved every thing: the question and the answers. :-) My best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano:  thank you my friend.  ;)  Happy Holidays and, of course, Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

On rewriting the equation,

$$\frac{1}{\ln x} = \ln\frac{x}{e} = \ln x - \ln e = \ln x -1$$
$$(\ln x)^2 - \ln x - 1 = 0$$
$$\ln x = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4}}{2} = \frac{1\pm\sqrt5}{2}$$

> $$x = \exp\left( \frac{1\pm\sqrt5}{2}\right)$$

Comment: $+1$ good spot. OP's numerical answer is the $(-)$ root

Comment: Thank You! Yeah.